How to make Huawei E3272 modem to work by COM port
I've got a LTE Huawei E3272 USB modem (so called "dongle") that works like a network card (WLAN) by its Hilink SW, I mean it's not seen as a device under COM ports as, eg., my older Huawei E3131 dongle.
My goal is to make this dongle to work by COM port to send AT commands to it. I'd like to get just a temporary modification of its modality from WLAN to COM port, just the time to send AT commands to it, I mean I'd like to avoid a permanent modification to COM modality unless I can restore it back to its original network card modality as soon as I finish my work with AT commands.
I've tried accessing E3272's debug mode to turn its modality into COM both by http://192.168.1.1/html/switchDebugMode.html and http://192.168.1.1/html/switchDebugMode.html both with and without .html but I was addressed to the main page without any result.

@Ramhound: Most LTE modems provide a serial-over-USB interface, usually switchable between binary QMI/MBIM mode and oldschool text-based AT command mode, and the OS recognizes them either as a "WWAN network interface" or as a traditional modem where you can ATDT*99# and get Internet, as you could with old 2G/3G cellphones. (Many provide several serial-over-USB interfaces; e.g. one for AT, one for data, one for GPS, something along those lines.)

@Ramhound
Afaik there's a sort of workaround to send AT commands to some Huawei WLAN modems as mine via putty by COM port, which is my definite goal, and it deals with downgrading modem's fw for first and then installing Huawei Mobile Partner drivers (instead of its native Hilink). The drawback of this solution for me is that this is a permanent changing as far as I understood on the contrary I'd like to keep on using this modem in its WLAN modality and with its Hilink SW, in other words I don't know how to restore it back to WLAN.
I could give the link of this solution if this is permitted.

@grawity_u1686
Do you mean you know how to switch my modem to send AT commands to it? If yes, tell me please.

Which OS are you using? For Linux, yes, but for Windows I don't think you can change which of the two magic commands the driver sends.

I run a dual boot windows 10 / ubuntu 24. So can I run your solution in my ubuntu environment? If yes, could you please explain it to me step-by-step?

usb_modeswitch should be in the Ubuntu repositories (if not already installed). This is the only tool I know but it was typically used to switch from mass storage device - that some modems used in order to expose a small flash drive containing the (Windows) driver and software - to modem. I don't know if it can be used for your specific scenario or how to use it for such purpose.

Please explain me this: is giving AT commands to a usb modem/dongle like mine a different thing from the modality (wlan/com) it's seen by the OS? Maybe I was wrong but I thought it was necessary to change its modality for first (wlan->com) to make possible to give it AT commands. How does that work?

With Huawei, the way it works is that the modem first pretends to be a CD-ROM until the driver (or usb_modeswitch) sends it a magic command to show up as a modem of either type. And in this case, there are two such commands (cdrom-to-AT and cdrom-to-hilink). I'll post (or someone else might post) a full answer if I remember, but the gist is that you'll need to either edit usb_modeswitch config to use the other command, or turn off the automatic usb_modeswitch entirely so that you could run it with the other option yourself.
